# How to use associative array in JavaScript to retrieve users?

Tags: javascript

The goal is to list users in rooms, so a room can contain many users and should be easily retrieved:

ex:

```
user1 = {"username":"john","sex":"male"};
user2 = {"username":"robert","sex":"male"};
user3 = {"username":"isac","sex":"male"};

rooms["room1"].push(user1);
rooms["room1"].push(user2);
rooms["room2"].push(user3);
```

and then

```
return rooms["room1"];
```

should return

```
{"username":"john","sex":"male"};
{"username":"robert","sex":"male"};
```

of course `rooms[roomName].push(user2);` is not good

Any idea on how to achieve that ?

Comment: `of course rooms[roomName].push(user2); is not good` What?

Comment: it gives ERROR  : no such method !

Comment: If `roomName` is `"room1"` or `"room2"`, there is no reason for an error.

Comment: It's because `rooms[roomName]` is an array that doesn't exist yet, and you can't call the `push` method on and array that doesn't exist. Plalx has the right idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var roomsMap = {
    room1: [],
    room2: [],
    room3: []
};

roomsMap.room1.push(user1);
```

or if you need the key to be dynamic:

```
roomsMap[roomKey].push(someUser);
```

EDIT:

> almost good. But how to make roomsMap Dynamic as well and not be
>   restricted to room1, room2, room3 ?

You could do it this way to dynamically add new key/array to the `roomsMap`.

```
(roomsMap[roomKey] = roomsMap[roomKey] || []).push(user1);
```

Complete example:

```
var roomsMap = {},
    user1 = {"username":"john","sex":"male"},
    roomKey = 'room1';

(roomsMap[roomKey] = roomsMap[roomKey] || []).push(user1);

console.log(roomsMap[roomKey]); //[Object { username="john", sex="male"}]
```

Comment: almost good.
But how to make roomsMap Dynamic as well and not be restricted to room1, room2, room3 ?